# Centos-Webpanel Server Module, Login to Control Panel 404 error in WHMCS

Tags: php, whmcs, centos-web-panel

I have installed the Centos-Webpanel WHMCS Server Module in WHMCS.

Once in WHMCS, usually we are able to configure such addon modules such that one can click on a link within WHMCS in order to be directed straight to the CWP Administrator Dashboard on the VPS.

In WHMCS Admin Dashboard,

Setup>Servers>ServerName>Login to Control Panel

404 error URL https://host.domain.com:/login.php

Actual URL https://host.domain.com:/login/index.php (if not logged in)

Module php code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j9YSJJCRbGpRgKntlujVAHwUiYXL162c/view?usp=sharing)

google "inspect Elements"[image] image attached

I am not sure whether the error is caused at the whmcs end, or in the module index.php?

**EDIT....**

I have a solution to this problem...i edited the CWP WHMCS Module php code. Changed to look like the following; (note :2031/login/index.php. Fomerly this was :2031/index.php)

```
> function cwp7_AdminLink($params) {
>     $code = '<form action="https://'.$params["serverhostname"].':2031/login/index.php"
> method="post" target="_blank">
>         <input type="hidden" name="user" value="'.$params["serverusername"].'" />
>         <input type="hidden" name="password" value="'.$params["serverpassword"].'" />
>         <input type="submit" value="Login to Control Panel" />
>         </form>';
>     return $code;
```

I feel that there still remains the problem of passing the username and password for root user into a web browser. That to me is a bad idea...and this part of the code should be removed completely (i have not done that)